# GlacierSelectNotAvailable: Glacier select retrievals are currently not available, please try again later

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-glacier

When I restore glacier archive file in s3,I am facing with **GlacierSelectNotAvailable** error.
I try to setting up the params of restoreObject but I keep getting that error.
I use Nodejs AWS SDK.

```
var params = {
    Bucket: 'test_bucket',
    Key: 'userInfo_glacier.csv',
    RequestPayer: 'requester',
    RestoreRequest: {
      OutputLocation: {
        S3: {
          BucketName: 'test_bucket',
          Prefix: 'test',
          StorageClass: 'GLACIER',
        }
      },
      SelectParameters: {
        Expression: 'SELECT * FROM Object',
        ExpressionType: 'SQL',
        InputSerialization: {
          CSV: {
            Comments: '#',
            FieldDelimiter: ',',
            FileHeaderInfo: 'IGNORE',
            QuoteCharacter: '"',
            QuoteEscapeCharacter: '"',
            RecordDelimiter: '\n'
          }
        },
        OutputSerialization: {
          CSV: {
            FieldDelimiter: ',',
            QuoteCharacter: '"',
            QuoteEscapeCharacter: '"',
            QuoteFields: 'ASNEEDED',
            RecordDelimiter: '\n'
          }
        }
      },
      Tier: 'Expedited',
      Type: 'SELECT'
    }
  };

  s3.restoreObject(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err.stack); // an error occurred
    else console.log('data--', data); // successful response
  });
```

Comment: `Expedited` is not applicable to `DEEP_ARCHIVE` objects.  What's the storage class of this object?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thank you for your information.I already tried with `Standard` and `Bulk` but same error.Storage class is Glacier.

Comment: Getting the same error. Did you manage to get past it? Or was it just a temporary error?

Answer (score 1):

> GlacierSelectNotAvailable: Glacier Select retrievals are currently not available. Please try again later.

It's not a problem with your code, it's just as they say, you can't use Glacier Select at this time so you just have to wait and try again later.

It's not clear if the error is caused by downtime, traffic, whether it happens to certain accounts, all accounts or on retrieval requests hitting specific regions. I was getting the same error so I set up a POST request to perform the select directly and still got the same error.

I kept retrying the exact same POST request once a day, and two days later it was working.

Retrievals are pretty rare and costly in Glacier so don't expect them to always be readily available when you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's related with the Provisioned Capacity that you have on S3. As AWS says on the docs:

```
"Provisioned Capacity ensures that retrieval capacity for Expedited retrievals is available when you need it"
```

Keep in mind that `"Each unit of capacity provides that at least three expedited retrievals can be performed every five minutes and provides up to 150 MB/s of retrieval throughput."`

More info here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/downloading-an-archive-two-steps.html#api-downloading-an-archive-two-steps-retrieval-options